# How to get value from input component element in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs

This is my code:

```
xtype: 'component',
autoEl: {
    html: '<input type="text">'
},
listeners: {
    render: function(_component) {
        _component.getEl().on('keyup', function(e) {
            console.log(_component.getValue());
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to output the value of the input each time a key is pressed in the input.  However, the console outputs an error that reads, "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getValue'"

How can I get the value of this textbox?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* it is better to declare the event the "ExtJS" way.

```
xtype: 'panel',
items: [
    { xtype: 'textfield', id: 'inputtext' }
]
```

And in your controller:

```
onLaunch: function () {
    this.control({
        '#inputtext': {
            keyup: function(e) {
               console.log(e.getValue());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My thought is that ExtJS don't really like we mess with the DOM directly

Comment: Thanks, but I am quite new to extJs and I don't know how to insert that into my controller.  My controller is just `Ext.define('RateManagement.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller'
});
` and the code I posted above is in my view (views/Main.js).

Comment: Just add the "onLaunch" part of the post right after the extend property (Before the closing curly bracket). I suggest you strongly to look at the wide range of example you can find on the subject: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/

Comment: In your example, where is `_component` defined?

Comment: I changed your component by a panel. But it's changeable, panel is a specific type of component. But you should not use _component directly. It is not a good practice.

Comment: For instance, in my code I set `_component` here `render: function(_component) {` but where do you have me set it in your example?  I ask because I can't get this code to work. No errors are thrown in console.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. I've edited my answer. But you should have had an error. It's weird